# What happens to this theorem if we change the dimension of the spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

We have the following theorem

> Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a compact operator between the Hilbert spaces $X,Y$. Then there exist (possibly finite) orthonormal bases $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots \}$ and $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots \}$ of $X,Y$ and (possibly finite) numbers $s_1,s_2,\ldots$ such that $s_n \rightarrow 0$ (if there are countably many numbers), such that 
>   $$
> Tx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}s_n \left<x,e_n \right>f_n
> $$

This is the singular value decomposition for operators between Hilbert spaces.

My questions are: If $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional then the theorem, as stated above is true? If $X$ is finite dimensional, both orthonormal bases become finite, since then we work in $T(X)$ which is a finite dimensional subspace in the (possible infinite dimensional) space $Y$.

But what happens, if $X$ is infinite dimensional, but $Y$ is not? Are the orthonormal bases in that case still finite?

Comment: Several missing words make this question difficult to understand. Please proofread it sometime soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one space is infinite-dimensional and the other is finite-dimensional, you have finite orthonormal **sets**, but obviously not an orthonormal **basis** of the infinite-dimensional one.  Similarly if $X$ and $Y$ are finite-dimensional but with different dimensions, you don't get a basis of the larger one. Even in the case where $X=Y$, it's not at all clear to me that  $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$ can both be taken to be bases, rather than just orthonormal sets.